# Related to python for string comparison from file1 and file 2

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am a beginner of Python so I require your help for solving the following issue.
I'd like to take strings from file1 and search in file2 and store the data in array.

```
Ex- "abhishek" =0 file1 
"abhishek" =1 file2
```

Then I have to store both values 0 and 1 in an array.